# Check sequential numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, powerbi

I have a list of  aprox 25 numbers that should be sequentials. I have to find if there is any missing. Ie, having:
...
60001231
60001232
60001234
...

I need to somehow detect the missing "60001233".
In Excel it's pretty easy but this is such a large database and i'm a total beginner in SQL or Power BI. Im thinking in a calculated column but I don't understand how to insert a "lag" operator to substract one number with the previous.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is really inefficient in MS Access, but . . . with just a few numbers, it should be fine:

```
select n, next_n
from (select t.*,
             (select t.*,
                     min(t2.n) as next_n
              from t t2
              where t2.n > t.n
             ) as t
       from t
      ) t
where next_n <> n + 1;
```

The innermost subquery calculates the "next" value for each row.  The outer query then filters this so only non-adjacent values are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to *present* the missing numbers as well. If so, study my old article:

[Find and Generate Missing Values in an Access Table](https://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

It also holds links to a demo (in .mdb format) as well as full code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Solution

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1YlWMgKTxmDSVCk2FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index1", {"Index.1"}, #"Added Index1", {"Index"}, "Added Index1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Index1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Index1", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Added Index1",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Custom", each if [Index]=1 then [Column1]-1 else [Column1.1]),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [Column1]-[Custom]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each if [Custom.1]<>1 then "not consecutive" else "consecutive"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Index.1", "Column1.1", "Custom", "Custom.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let-

1. Your table name is - **your_table_name**
2. Number column name is - **number_column**

**Now,** create a new table with this below **Advanced Editor** code-

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {}, {{"max", each List.Max([number_column]), type nullable number}, {"min", each List.Min([number_column]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.Range({[min]..[max]},0)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"max", "min"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"Custom"}, your_table_name, {"number_column"}, "your_table_name", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded your_table_name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "your_table_name", {"number_column"}, {"your_table_name.number_column"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded your_table_name", each ([#"your_table_name.number_column"] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"your_table_name.number_column"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

The above new **Table** will now return the list of numbers missing in the base table.

Sample data and output-

[image]